# USA gmaps map integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a custom image, on top of the USA.
Basically, I need only USA displayed + overlay image on it.

What I can get working is, 100% exact what I need but for Finland.
I can't understand how to tweak it, to work the same way but for USA.

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(64.8, 24.8)
var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 24);
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,

    styles: [
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  codeAddress('Turku')
  codeAddress('Naantali')
  codeAddress('Oulu')
  codeAddress('Imatra')
  codeAddress('Mannerheimintie 2, Helsinki')

  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(59.8, 19.3);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(69.0, 31.2);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

  var srcImage = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Finland_Regions_Map.svg/2000px-Finland_Regions_Map.svg.png';

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
// [END region_initialization]

// [START region_constructor]
/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvvy5vxz/2/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to include everything in the question itself, you can edit it to contain the fiddle as well. Comments is really just for "comments"

Comment: You might start with an equivalent of the [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Finland_Regions_Map.svg/2000px-Finland_Regions_Map.svg.png) for the US.

Comment: @geocodezip That is not the problem...

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: @geocodezip When I set the Lat/Li to the USA ones, then It got messy and no image is displayed...

Comment: @LubomirLubenov Don't show us the code that's working for Finland, show us the code that's not working for the USA.

Comment: Maybe you could share that with us.  A not working version of what you are trying to do would be more useful than a working version of what you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own.
I'm posting the working JS code, thanks!

```
 <script>

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39, -95)
var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 24);
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,

    styles: [
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  function codeAddress(address,personName) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: personName
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }


  codeAddress('23361 El Toro Rd, 219 Lake Forest, CA 92630','23361 El Toro Rd, 219 Lake Forest, CA 92630')
  codeAddress('4634 Longfellow Dr New Orleans, LA 70127','4634 Longfellow Dr New Orleans')
  codeAddress('70 Main St,New Hampton, NH 03256','70 Main St,New Hampton, NH 03256')
  codeAddress('1701 Broadway,Seattle, WA 98122','1701 Broadway,Seattle, WA 98122')


  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(24.5, -125.2);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(49.4, -66.8);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

  var srcImage = 'http://bootstrap.mapsmith.net/img/USA-Mercator.svg';
  //var srcImage = 'https://i.imgsafe.org/106e093026.png';


  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
// [END region_initialization]

// [START region_constructor]
/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```